# Converting Obj-C init override function into Swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift3, initialization, overriding, subclass

How can I rewrite the *initWithDevice:* function in *MyViewControllerB* into Swift 3?

**MyViewControllerA**

```
@interface MyViewControllerA : UIViewController
- (instancetype)initWithDevice:(DeviceClass *)device;
@end

@implementation MyViewControllerA
- (instancetype)initWithDevice:(DeviceClass *)device
{
    self = [super init];
    if ( self ) {
        // set a bunch of properties 
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**MyViewControllerB**

```
@interface MyViewControllerB : MyViewControllerA
    - (instancetype)initWithDevice:(DeviceClass *)device;
@end

@implementation MyViewControllerB
- (instancetype)initWithDevice:(DeviceClass *)device
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil]) {
        // init stuff for subclass
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: try this http://objc.to/jlzy3h

Comment: try this https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/converter/

Comment: Thanks, guys!  Nice tool.  @AntonyRaphel - I also had to add the following:

   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

If you want to post the solution, I'll accept.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, can you edit my answer again and I will review it. It  was automatically rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for **Swift 3.0** and **Swift 2.2**

```
override init(device: DeviceClass) {
super.init(nibName: "AnotherViewController", bundle: nil)

// init stuff for subclass

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){ 
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
}
```

You can try with your **Objective-c** code into **Swift** by using this site also: [objectivec2swift](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home/main)